# VTD-XML creating an XML document

Tags: vtd-xml

I am a bit confused on how to do this, all of the docs / examples show how to read and edit xml docs but there doesn't seem to be any clear way of creating an xml from scratch, I would rather not have to ship my program with a dummy xml file in order to edit one. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by creating an XML document? Programmatically (in terms of API) or something else?

Comment: I meant programmatically, sorry I thought that was clear from the context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do instead would be to just hard-code an empty document like this:

```
byte[] emptyDoc = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root></root>".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

And then use that to create your VTDGen and XMLModifier, and start adding elements:

```
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.setDoc(emptyDoc);
vg.parse(true);

VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);

// Cursor is at root, update Root Element Name
xm.updateElementName("employee");

xm.insertAttribute(" id='6'");
xm.insertAfterHead("<name>Bob Smith</name>");
vn = xm.outputAndReparse();

// etc...
```

Comment: If by getBytes() you mean getBytes("UTF-8").